Problema con redirect luego de terminar hilo spring
Buen dia compañeros.
Estoy tratando de mostrar una vista mientras se ejecuta una tarea, pero al terminar de ejecutarse la tarea no entra mi redirect y no se por que!!!!!
Este es el bloque donde esta el problema
 @GetMapping("/services")
    public ModelAndView services(Model model) throws IOException {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("components/loader");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Deteniendo servicios...");
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::stopServicesIfs).whenCompleteAsync((v,e) ->{
            redirectToBackup(modelAndView);
        });


        return modelAndView;
    }

al entrar a la ruta /services de inmediato se muestra la vista (loader) se detienen los servicios de forma correcta, pero no entra en el redirect, esta es la funcion para redireccionar
//Redireccionar al backUp
    private void redirectToBackup(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/backUp");
    }

espero alguien pueda ayudarme, ya llevo mucho tiempo con este problema

Buen día.
Tuve que tomar un enfoque diferente, lo que hice fue:
En la vista de loader, hago una petición a un nuevo end point que devuelve el estado de los servicios, si ya se detuvieron manda un true, si no se han detenido manda false, la rediccion no se hace hasta que se recibe el true, pero se hace desde el front.
Muchas gracias, saludos.
